# How can I add a list of endpoints to @CrossOrigin annotation in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

How can I add multiple specific endpoints to the parameters of the @CrossOrigin annotation? E.g. Both http://localhost:9000 and http://localhost:4200

```
  @Controller
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class HelloController {

        @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
        @RequestMapping("/hello")
        @ResponseBody
        public String sayHello() {
            return "Hello World Developer!!!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. You can supply a list

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"${client.url}", "${client.url2}")
```

..and in the application.yaml

```
client:
  url: http://localhost:4200
  url2: http://localhost:4201
```